# Convert stdole.StdPicture to System.Drawing.Icon

Tags: c#, vb6, interop, .net-2.0

I have a COM object (VB6 ActiveX exe) that returns a stdole.StdPicture through interop.  Is there a way to convert that to a System.Drawing.Icon?  Or is there a better return type for my COM object to return?

What I'm trying to do is have my C# code use an icon from my VB6 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, through trial and error I found the solution.

In the VB6 code, return the icon handle instead of the icon (the return type for Icon.Handle is OLE_HANDLE which can be returned as a long.

In the VB6 code:

```
Public Function GetIconHandle() as long

     GetIconHandle = myForm.Icon.Handle

End Function
```

In the .NET code:

```
IntPtr iconHandle = (IntPtr)COMDll.GetIconHandle(); // returns an int for the handle to the icon.
Icon myIcon = Icon.FromHandle(iconHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445742(VS.60).aspx) of the StdPicture is vbPicTypeIcon then you can call:

```
var icon = Icon.FromHandle(pic.Handle);
```

Comment: I tried that--throws System.RuntimeInteropServices.COMException: Catastrophic failure

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for that? I get my error here: var pic = user.GetPicture(); (Catastrophic failure)